# Get sheet names from multiple files which match a vector

Tags: r

I have multiple files and I want to only read specific sheets from them

```r
path <- paste0("", sheets$file[1:nrow(sheets)])
```

`sheets$file` column has names of the files `test1.xlsx` in the rows

```r
sheet_names <- lapply(path, readxl::excel_sheets)
```

`sheets$table` has the sheet names I want to extract from the sheetnames created - how do I do this?

This achieves the goal but in a complicated way:

```r
sheet <- sheet_names %>% 
  map_df(as_tibble)

rel_sheet <- as.list(sheet[sheet$value %in% sheets$table,])
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your examples to test, but would something like this be simple enough?

```r
library(purrr)

# simple function to read each sheet from a given workbook (into a list of data frames)
read_sheets <- function(single_path, sheets) map(sheets, ~readxl::read_excel(single_path, .x))

# loop over the list of files, reading in
map(path, read_sheets, sheets = sheets$table)
```

Your end result will be a list of lists of data frames. From there, all depends on what your data looks like.